# configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute, Azure Api

Tags: azure, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, database-connection

I made an azure web app. When I go to my web app URL it says the app is up and running, https://nameofmyapp.azurewebsites.net/.

When I try to go send a request for the web API by going to https://nameofmyapp.azurewebsites.net/api/Menus to get JSON text I receive this error

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The connection string 'PetSchedulerDbContext' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.\"",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n
```

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PetschedulerDbContext"  connectionString="Server=tcp:petschedulerserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=petschedulerdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=Julia;Password=Network5!;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have tried changing the provider name to

providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"

with the same result. I don't understand what the required provider name would be? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my cents for this issue:

**Prerequisite**: Please make sure you have the same set of connection string value in the Azure portal Web app configuration setting as well.

- If you are using designed based approach, then you need to define the connections string that the designer generates and which looks something like this:

```html
   <add name="Northwind_Entities"  
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Northwind.csdl|  
                                res://*/Northwind.ssdl|  
                                res://*/Northwind.msl;  
                       provider=System.Data.SqlClient;  
                       provider connection string=  
                           &quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;  
                                 Initial Catalog=Northwind;  
                                 Integrated Security=True;  
                                 MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"  
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

- If you're not using the designer (if you don't have an .edmx file), the connection string should look like this:

```html
<add name="ConnectionStringName"     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"     connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN

https://forums.asp.net/t/1858681.aspx?The+connection+string+EFDbContext+in+the+application+s+configuration+file+does+not+contain+the+required+providerName+attribute+

Hope it helps.